# Python and/or django solution for reading log files on linux?

Tags: python, django, logging, syslog, logrotate

I would like my Django application to be able to display local syslog etc files.  I would like to avoid writing the logic for managing `.1`,`.2` etc rotated files, and get an object for each log that I can retrieve a set of rows from.

Is there any such python library, or even better, any such django app?

Clarification: I don't want to write messages to a log, I want to read the messages that are already there.

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577968-log-watcher-tail-f-log/

Answer (score -1):

Python has a [`syslog`](http://docs.python.org/library/syslog.html) module. You can also use [`SysLogHandler`](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1915/).

Comment: Does that handle rotated files as well?

Comment: I believe all the log rotation is handled by `syslog` itself, although I haven't used it so I'm not sure.

Comment: Both of those appear to be for writing messages to syslog, whereas I am trying to display the contents of the logs.